# I was given a Lego set bag with no box or instructions - mostly blacks, whites, greys, browns

Tags: set-identification

I was given a bag of a Lego set with no box or instructions and my kid wants to build it. The bag number is 5, from 2017. QR code and picture of pieces attached.

[image: QR Code]

[image: Lego Pieces mostly blacks, whites, greys, browns]

Comment: Unfortunately, the bag QR code only identifies the bag, which would be in many, many different sets; similarly, the 2017 copyright only applies to the bag, which would be in use for many years after that point.

Comment: If you only got bag 5, it's not a complete set, and as such it won't be possible possible to build the set.

Comment: That isn't bag 5, that's a [plastic code for polypropylene](https://methodrecycling.com/gb/journal/recycling-101-what-do-the-plastic-codes-mean#:~:text=%235%20pp%20%E2%80%93%20polypropylene)

Comment: Any number you see inside of a recycling symbol will be about the material. It has nothing to do with the purpose of the contents.

Answer (score 13):

Based on

- Pearl Gold Plate, Modified 1 x 1 with Tooth Vertical
- Black Wedge, Plate A-Shape with 2 Rows of 4 Studs
- Dark Bluish Gray Wedge, Plate 3 x 3 Cut Corner

[71719-1 Zane's Mino Creature](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=71719-1)

[image: 71719-1 Zane's Mino Creature]

Comment: Looks good. This set also has "Wedge 4 x 3 No Studs Stepped" (Black), and "Wedge 4 x 4 Fractured Polygon Top" (dark Bluish gray) which appear in the question

Comment: @roblogic I don't think I even knew such a piece existed.